# Different textures on iPhone app launch image?

Tags: ios5, ios6, uinavigationbar

I am trying to make a launch screen that is very similar to the first screen on the app. However, I notice that the iOS 5 & 6 navigation bar "textures" are slightly different.

Is there a way to perhaps show different launch images based on version, or indeed another way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is 'no'. 
Ideally you should be able to set 'UILaunchImageFile' key value in  info.plist. But since there is no such predefined key to get the current os version of the device, you will not be able to specify any dynamic file name.